Equivalent Function between Qlik and PowerBI
I am doing migration report from Qlik to PowerBI.
I am wondering how to change this Qlik function into PowerBi.
=Num(Count(distinct {1 <[Type]-='Other',SaleDate=P(MasterCalenderDate)> } [CustomerId]) , '###,###,####')

Any help ?

Could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

I understood that you want to count  distinct CustomerId where the type is different from 'Other' and where the SaleDate matches the MasterCalendarDate :
NumCustomers = 
FORMAT(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            ALL(CustomerTable), 
            CustomerTable[Type] <> "Other" && 
            CustomerTable[SaleDate] IN VALUES(MasterCalendar[MasterCalendarDate])
        )
    ), 
    "###,###,####"
)

